# EditText using layout UI

Tags: android, android-edittext

In android studio we can create layout using drag and drop UI but i can't see any drag and drop for EditText, is it not given or missing in Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

It is called Plain Text in graphic editor.

[image]

alternatively you can write these lines of code in text editor

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use drag and drop edit, you have different preconfigured `EditText`'s. You can choose which one is suits you best.

[image]
[image]